# How can I find the Id property or properties related to a navigational property?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-6

For a project I'm working with Entity Framework and I'd like to be able to enumerate all navigational properties for a given object instance (assuming it's an object generated by EF). From there I'd like to get the related Id property for every navigational property.

For example, if I get an instance of the class `Person`, I want to be able to find it's navigational properties called `Address` and `Boss`. For those two navigational properties I want to then "lookup" the related Id properties called `AddressId` and `BossId`.

I need those Id properties so I can run queries on a different database which does not have the same foreign keys but does have exactly the same Ids.

So far I have figured out a way to get the [RelationshipManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.relationshipmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a random object instance generated by EF. And while debugging I can get to the foreign key relations via the Manager's `Relationships` property. But I can only get as far as the navigational property name. So I can see there's a `FK_Person_Address` which is related to the navigational property called `Address` but I can't find the `AddressId`.

So my question is, how can I dynamically (with no knowledge of the `Person` class' layout) discover the `AddressId` property which is related to `Address`?

I am aware the Foreign Key relationship might have the Id property on the other side of the relation (`Boss` pointing to `Person` in stead of `Person` having a `BossId`). In that case, I'd still like to discover that `Boss` has a `PersonId` when I'm inspecting an instance of `Person`.

Comment: are you using code first to generate tables?

Comment: nope, database first

Comment: Are you wanting this at build or runtime?

Comment: Since the model is not going to change at runtime and the entire model is known at compile time, either build or runtime ought to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a dictionary with all navigation properties as Key and all related properties as Value (the value might be a property from the other entity)

Add these to your DBContext class and call `db.GetForeignKeyProperties<Person>()`

The result will be something like:

"Address" - "AddressID"

"Boss" - "Person.BossID"

```
public Dictionary<string,string> GetForeignKeyProperties<DBType>()
{
    EntityType table = GetTableEntityType<DBType>();
    Dictionary<string, string> foreignKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (NavigationProperty np in table.NavigationProperties)
    {
        var association = (np.ToEndMember.DeclaringType as AssociationType);
        var constraint = association.ReferentialConstraints.FirstOrDefault();



        if (constraint != null && constraint.ToRole.GetEntityType() == table)
            foreignKeys.Add(np.Name, constraint.ToProperties.First().Name);

        if (constraint != null && constraint.FromRole.GetEntityType() == table)
            foreignKeys.Add(np.Name, constraint.ToProperties.First().DeclaringType.Name+"."+constraint.ToProperties.First().Name);
    }

    return foreignKeys;
}

private EntityType GetTableEntityType<DBType>()
{
    return GetTableEntityType(typeof(DBType));
}

private EntityType GetTableEntityType(Type DBType)
{
    ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
    MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    EntityType table = workspace.GetEdmSpaceType((StructuralType)workspace.GetItem<EntityType>(DBType.FullName, DataSpace.OSpace)) as EntityType;
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Good sir, this is exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. I spent quote some time searching how to do this a while ago too.

Comment: Crashes with self-references: tries to add the same name to the dictionary twice. I would add a parameter whether you want the 'from' or 'to' FKs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that returns key values of know entity objects:

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>> GetKeyValues<T>(DbContext db, 
                                                        IEnumerable<T> entities)
    where T : class
{
    var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
    return entities.Select (e => oc.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(e))
                   .Select(objectStateEntry => objectStateEntry.EntityKey)
                   .Select(ek => ek.EntityKeyValues
                                   .ToDictionary (x => x.Key, y => y.Value));
}
```

This method uses the underlying `ObjectContext` API to obtain `ObjectStateEntry` objects that belong to each entity object. The `EntityKey` contains the key value(s) of an entity as a key-value pair. (Entities with composite keys have more than one key value.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm actually already using `EntityKeyValues` for a different purpose. I'd like to get a list of all the foreign keys, not the primary keys as your code provides. Or can `EntityKeyValues` also be used to retrieve foreign keys somehow?

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the lookup part of your question. What you want is less obvious and I don't know any way to do it at this moment, maybe later.